# Nothing is displayed on the page after running npm start

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, reactjs, electron

I am currently on the backend of my software which runs via electron but I can't get the data. So I tried to retrieve the data from a python program that sends it using Flask, but when I run the `npm start` command, nothing is displayed. I would also like to be able to run the program via electron but when I run the command `npm run electron:start` nothing happens either.

Here are the JS, Python code:

**JS** :

```
import React from "react";

class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.hello = require("child_process").spawn("python", ["./hello.py"]);
        this.state = { fs_s5: 12 };
        this.hello.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
          this.setState({ fs_s5: data });
        });
    }
    render(){
        return(
        <div>
            <div class="home">
                <div class="template-1" id="temp1">
                <div class="panel-1">
                    <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1>Panel 1</h1>
                    <i class='bx bx-cog modal-trigger-panel'></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="sec-5 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-5">
                        <span class="h1" id="h1-fs-s5">{this.state.fs_s5}</span>
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s5</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec-4 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-4">
                        <h1>--</h1>
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s4</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec-3 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-3">
                        <h1>--</h1>
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s3</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec-2 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-2">
                        <h1>--</h1>
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s2</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec-1 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-1">
                        <h1>--</h1>
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s1</h3>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

**Python** :

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World! This is powered by Python backend."

if __name__ == "__main__":
   print(12)
   time.sleep(5)
   app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

---

**Package.json** :

```
{
  "name": "react-electron",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "main": "public/main.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "electron:serve": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn start\" \"yarn electron:start\"",
    "electron:build": "yarn build && electron-builder -c.extraMetadata.main=build/main.js",
    "electron:start": "wait-on tcp:3001 && electron ."
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "browser": {
    "child_process": false
  }
}
```

**Test :**

For each test I performed, no software window opened.

First, I tested to use HTTP to send data from my python program to the .js program with the following code parts but no data was sent since when I tried to go to the following address `http://127.0.0.1:5000` the connection failed:

**JS**:

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { data: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/data')
      .then(response => this.setState({ data: response.data }));
  }
```

**Python**:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/data')
def get_data():
  data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

On the other hand, when I went to the address `http:localhost:3000` the GUI was displayed but without the data in the corresponding box.

Secondly, I tested to retrieve the data through the stdout() function with the following code:

**JS**:

```
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.hello = require("child_process").spawn("python", ["./hello.py"]);
        this.state = { fs_s5: 12 };
        this.hello.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
          this.setState({ fs_s5: data });
        });
    }
```

**Python**:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print(1)
```

But I had a failed connection for the URL: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000' and nothing for the URL 'http://localhost:3000'

**So, I would like the python program to send the same list of data continuously to the React program.**

Regards,

Comment: From your `package.json` it looks as though you should use `npm run electron:serve`. Does this work? If not, please make sure to include a [mcve] because since we don't know how your app tries to connect to the Flask server (is `hello.py` the Python snippet you've already shared?), or how React and Flask are connected, this is not reproducible. Are you expecting Flask to output the data to stdout? This won't happen, since you define an HTTP route but never make a request to it, it seems...

Comment: I had indeed used the wrong command to run the software, however nothing starts when I try the 'npm run electron:serve' command. I don't know how to snippet the software.

Comment: Also, I think the problem is indeed that I'm not querying for the data on stdout. But I don't know what line of code I'm missing to be able to retrieve data in my React program? and does the fact that the data can't be retrieved prevent the program from displaying the code?

Comment: So you're starting a Flask app on `127.0.0.1:5000`, which expects an *HTTP* request to `/`, but expect it to write to stdout? No, if you're using HTTP, you'll have to make an HTTP request. Ofc there's no data in stdout because it would be returned to the client (browser or Electron) making the request over HTTP. If you want to retrieve the data via `stdout`, don't use Flask, but simply `print()` in the Python script. Unless I'm missing something critical here, this should do the trick. Also, try running you Electron app and browsing to `http://127.0.0.1:5000` in your browser.

Comment: What is potentially the best data transfer solution if I choose to continuously send a list of data and get it back into the React program?
When I run the command 'npm run electron:serve' and put in the address `http://127.0.0.1:5000`, nothing happens. I had followed this tutorial to add React with electron: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAaS9ix8pes&t=208s&ab_channel=JustinBrooks

Comment: Where do you put in the address? Your normal browser? You should see, at least in your Dev Tools' "Network" tab, a response with "Hello World!...". Does your application open at all (i.e., do you see the Electron window popping up)? Again, neither Electron nor React are the problem here. You have to choose (and understand) the mode of data transfer between Python and JS. Reading HTTP from stdout *won't work*. Again, try a simple Python script, simply `print("1")` for example. Your current JS code should receive the 1 you "sent" from Python.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to correctly state what your problem is, what you have tried and what the expected outcome is, as per [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: I put the address in my normal browser, it was written that the connection had failed. Also, no window opens when I run the npm run electron:serve command. When I just put print(1) in the python program, no window opens either.

Comment: I have re-edited my post with the ones I have currently tested.

Comment: Changing the Python code shouldn't change anything on whether your app opens correctly or not. Thus, I suggest you tackle one issue at a time; it may be worthwhile to debug why your app doesn't even open. Getting any errors on any console? Since you haven't shared any [mcve], I cannot reproduce your issue with the application not opening and thus am out of clues. Also I suggest that you search for (comprehensive) tutorials of the technologies in use as there may be multiple misunderstandings leading to various errors here (the import in the new Python snippet isn't needed, print is builtin).

Comment: It's ok, everything works, I was able to get a software window to open when I run npm start and the python program sends the data to the React program by watching this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LNl2JlZKHA&ab_channel=ArpanNeupane. I didn't install Flask properly, nor launch the python program so it was normal that I don't have access to the URL `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/data`.

Comment: I have one last question how to launch the python program when launching the npm start command since I only launched it via the `python hello.py` command in another terminal ?